# Cannot start XAMPP

Tags: apache2, mysql, lamp

When I try to start XAMPP with  /opt/lampp/lampp start command it gives me a message like this.

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.7.7...
XAMPP: Another web server daemon is already running.
XAMPP: XAMPP-MySQL is already running.
XAMPP: XAMPP-ProFTPD is already running.
XAMPP for Linux started.
```

Comment: You have another apache installation running. Uninstall apache2, restart and try again

Comment: How can i uninstall apache2?

Comment: I don't really use XAMPP, but I don't see why you should uninstall Apache.  It seems more likely to my naive intuition that XAMPP was already started, along with MySQL and ProFTPD. Unless you installed those servers, plus XAMPP.  Personally, I find it simpler to just install the servers, and forget about the added layer of XAMPP.  Then, you know what's going on, and have more control.

Answer (score 2):

I have similar problem and found the issue caused another service already running on port 443 (SSL).

Check running listener: **sudo netstat -tunap | grep LISTEN**, Mine got *vmware-hostd* and *cupsd* listed.

Refer to http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html , we need turn of lamp's SSL service using this command: **sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stopssl** , the command deactivates the SSL support permanently.

Now you can start xampp: **sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start**

Comment: using this command in new versions: sudo /opt/lampp/lampp disablepssl

Answer (score 1):

You're assuming it's Apache, it may be something else. If it is Apache then try `sudo aptitude remove apache2`. It could be lighttpd (`sudo aptitude remove lighttpd`) or nginx (`sudo aptitude remove nginx`) or any number of other packages. To identify it you can use netstat:

`sudo netstat -pant | egrep ":80 .* LISTEN"`

The last field will identify the program using port 80.

---

> ' sudo: aptitude: command not found '

Looks like you don't have aptitude installed, I assume you have an old version of Ubuntu? You can use `apt-get` instead:

```
apt-get remove apache2
```

Comment: After tring :: ## ' sudo netstat -pant | egrep ":80 .* LISTEN" ' ##  Show that :: ## ' tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1117/apache2 ' ## .  Then Try :: ## ' sudo aptitude remove apache2 ' ##. Then Show message :: # ' sudo: aptitude: command not found ' #

Comment: On Oneiric 11.10 **aptitute** isn't installed by default.

Comment: @red_trumpet - interesting, thanks. I hadn't realised that

Answer (score 1):

To stop apache2 you can use following command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

and then you can try starting xampp

hopefully it will work .

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled apache2 in synaptic, then ran `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`
and it worked.